# Setting data type value to an element when it reaches the top of the viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a hex colour value stored on each section and when a section reaches the top of the screen (-180px for the header) I want to assign a css property to the header element in order to change the text colour as you scroll through the sections. I am not getting any errors and I am having trouble debugging this issue.

http://www.amypreston.co.uk/

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $header = $("header");
    var numberOfSections = $("section").length;   
    var sectionOffsets = [];
    var sectionColour = $("section").eq(i).data("colour");

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        sectionOffsets.push($("section").eq(i).offset().top);
    }            

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();            

        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
            if(scrollTop > sectionOffsets[i] - 180) {
                $header.css('color', 'sectionColour');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I haven't check all the code but: `$header.css('color', 'sectionColour');` should be: `$header.css('color', sectionColour);`

Comment: I have removed that syntax error. There has been no change to the result though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know if it happened by accident, but the line

```
var sectionColour = $("section").eq(i).data("colour");
```

is out of place. it uses a variable `i` which is only defined in the window scroll handler.

notice that you need to retrieve the section color each time the scroll handler runs, and not only on window load. you need to place this line from above in the loop inside the scroll handler.

Plus, as stated on the comments, you need to use the `sectionColour` as a variable, and not as a string like you do now. the single quote marks must be removed, so `'sectionColour'` turns into `sectionColour`.

here is your fixed code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var $header = $("header");
    var numberOfSections = $("section").length;   
    var sectionOffsets = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
        sectionOffsets.push($("section").eq(i).offset().top);
    }            

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();            

        for(var i = 0; i < numberOfSections; i++) {
            if(scrollTop > sectionOffsets[i] - 180) {
                var sectionColour = $("section").eq(i).data("colour");
                $header.css('color', sectionColour);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

On a side note, you could shorten your code into this:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
     $("section").each(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(this).offset().top - 180) {
            $("header").css('color', $(this).data("colour"));
        }
    });
}).scroll();
```

Comment: Very helpful answer. I have used your shortened version which using the each function.